# Mobile submenu, only the little arrow next to submenu name is clickable

Tags: menus

I am using astra theme on my website and have this problem:
Mobile submenu link that has little arrow next to it, it expands revealing other submenu items when clicked. It is custom link that I have created only to contain submenu items, url was set to # and later on deleted the "#" character. Problem is, only the arrow is clickable and not entire link/word, how can I fix that

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.